# pandas data frame plot multiple frames in 3D

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot two data frames in one graph in 3D

```
data1 = {'numbers': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'frequency': [5,2,1,6,9,3,8,2,0,5]} 
data2 = {'numbers': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'frequency': [19,12,1,26,19,33,28,28,10,5]} 
newdf = pd.DataFrame(data1)
newdf2= pd.DataFrame(data2)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
newdf.plot(kind='bar',x ='numbers', y='frequency',figsize=(10,5), color='thistle', width=.4, legend=True, alpha=0.8, ax=ax)
newdf2.plot(kind='bar',x ='numbers', y='frequency',figsize=(10,5), color='navy', width=.2,legend=True, alpha=1,ax=ax) 
plot.show()
```

This plots both graphs in one graph, but the y and z axes are transposed. I want to plot each data set in the z-plane with the numbers forming the x-axis and the frequency the y-axis. I don't understand from all the examples how to achieve this. I would also like to plot the bars as 3d bars. I am grateful for any help, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing because I don't have an example of the kind of output I'd like to see, but is the 3D graph you'd like to implement an example of the following: the y-axis is the type of data frame and the z-axis is the frequency.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = {'numbers': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'frequency': [5,2,1,6,9,3,8,2,0,5]} 
data2 = {'numbers': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'frequency': [19,12,1,26,19,33,28,28,10,5]} 
newdf = pd.DataFrame(data1)
newdf2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

yticks = [4,3,2,1,0]
ax.bar(newdf['numbers'], newdf['frequency'], zs=3, zdir='y', color='b', alpha=0.8)
ax.bar(newdf2['numbers'], newdf2['frequency'], zs=1, zdir='y', color='r', alpha=0.8)

ax.set_xlabel('number')
ax.set_ylabel('df_type')
ax.set_zlabel('frequency')

ax.set_yticks(yticks)

plt.show()
```

[image]

bar3d type

```
# ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz)
ax.bar3d(newdf['numbers'], 3, 0, dx=1, dy=1, dz=newdf['frequency'], color='b', alpha=0.6)
ax.bar3d(newdf2['numbers'], 0, 0, dx=1, dy=1, dz=newdf2['frequency'], color='r', alpha=0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make the bars 3D as well?  Very clear solution. What does the 111 in the add_subplot(111,projection ='3d') pertain to?

Comment: `ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, zsort='average')`Kindly refer to [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/mplot3d/hist3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-hist3d-py).

Comment: Thank you and for the referral to the documentation. I understand how to use this now thanks to your clarity

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I have at hand (can't find the link to the original).

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# datasets
data1 = {'numbers': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'frequency': [5,2,1,6,9,3,8,2,0,5]} 
data2 = {'numbers': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'frequency': [19,12,1,26,19,33,28,28,10,5]} 

newdf = pd.DataFrame(data1)
newdf2= pd.DataFrame(data2)

# put all the data in one place
# can use data1['frequency'] and data2['frequency'] directly
data = np.array([
        newdf['frequency'].values,
        newdf2['frequency'].values,
        ])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
colors = ["r","g","b"]*5  # for up to 15 sets of bars

# Draw 3D bars 
ncnt, nbins = data.shape[:2]
xs = np.arange(nbins)
for i in range(ncnt):
    ys = data[i]
    cs = [colors[i]] * nbins
    ax.bar(xs, ys.ravel(), zs=i, zdir='x', color=cs, alpha=0.8)

ax.set_xlabel('data_frame')
ax.set_ylabel('numbers')
ax.set_zlabel('frequency')

ax.set_xticks(range(data.shape[0]))    # 2 dataframes
ax.set_yticks(newdf['numbers'].values) # from 'numbers' column

plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image: output-plot]

Comment: A very xclear solution. The reason I accepted the one below is simply because it was shorter. I would like to accept and vote up both solutions. Can the bars be plotted three-dimensional as well?